# UIPicker view not displaying data from JSON array

Tags: json, nsmutablearray, nsarray, uipickerview

i have a UIPicker view for which i need to load the data from a JSON feed.
I am able to write the array data into NSLOG and display it , but not able to see it in the UIPickerview . please see the code below and help me

Please also let me know how we can make the UIPicker view appear when i click a UIbutton and close the UIPickerview when a value is selected .

```
#import "orderSamples.h"
#import "SBJson.h"
#import "JSON.h"

@implementation orderSamples

NSMutableArray *products;
NSArray *list;
NSMutableData *responseData;
/*
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}
 */

- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    [super viewDidLoad];

    products = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http JSON URL"]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self ];


}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response { 
    NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse"); 
    [responseData setLength:0]; 
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data]; 
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
[connection release];


list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//[responseData release];

NSDictionary *dictionary = [responseString JSONValue];
NSArray *response = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"products"] retain];

list = [response valueForKey:@"product_name"];

NSLog(@"Here is the products list: %@",[response valueForKey:@"product_name"]);

self.pickerData = list;
[list release];    
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [list count];

}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [list objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *str = [list objectAtIndex:row];
    NSLog(@"Selected : %@" , str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is this line of code:

```
list = [dictionary valueForKey:@"products"];
```

This is assigning an object to your "list" variable, but that object will be autoreleased. Instead try:

```
list = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"products"] retain];
```

And you should probably be using instance variables rather than global variables, although if you have only one network connection at a time it doesn't really matter much.

Comment: and when i try to change the row and print list objectAtIndex:1 i am able to NSLog the value . strange but it doesn't get displayed on the pickerView

Comment: I did tweak the code and tried few diff things but still dint work. I have updated wit my latest code. can anyone help.

Comment: found out the issue .. hardcoded array works in viewdidLoad method , but not in connectionDidFinishLoading method . UIPickerview doesn't seem to load there.